# Looping through sheets in Google Spreadsheet and using getSheetName()

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm writing a script to loop through each sheet in one spreadsheet and copy data from specific cells into a corresponding sheet on another spreadsheet.  I am getting an error on line 18 of the below code, however, stating that it can't call the getLastRow method of null.  I used a couple of Logger.log lines to check my variables and see that targetSheet is coming back as null.  Any advice on what I've got wrong?

```
//Export each sheet's daily data to another sheet *Test Version*
function exportReports() {
  var sourceSS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  //Open Back Production Record *Test Version*
  var targetSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1ZJKZi-UXvqyGXW9V7KVx8whxulZmx0HXt7rmgIJpUY4");
  var allSourceSheets = sourceSS.getSheets();

  //For-Loop to loop through hourly production sheets, running the move data for-loop on each
  for(var s in allSourceSheets){

    var loopSheet = allSourceSheets[s];
    var loopSheetName = loopSheet.getSheetName();
    var targetSheet = targetSS.getSheetByName(loopSheetName);
    Logger.log(s);
    Logger.log(loopSheet);
    Logger.log(targetSheet);
    Logger.log(loopSheetName);
    var targetRow = targetSheet.getLastRow()+1;
    var currentDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-5", "MM/dd/yy");

    targetSheet.getRange(targetRow, 1).setValue(currentDate);
    //For-Loop to move data from source to target
    for(var i=6;i<=10;i++){
      var sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange(i, 2);
      var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetRow, i-4);
      var holder = sourceRange.getValue();

      targetRange.setValue(holder);
    }
  }    
}
```

Comment: If you replace the not-recommended `for-in` loop with the traditional index loop, do you still have problems? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-a-bad-idea

Comment: Thank you; this was helpful for this issue and improving my knowledge in general.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the documentation on [getSheetByName](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheetByName(String)), if the target sheet name does not exist, then you get `null` as a return value.

> **getSheetByName(name)**
>   Returns a sheet with the given name.
>
> If multiple sheets have the same name, the leftmost one is returned. Returns null if there is no sheet with the given name.

So, the desired sheet with name specified by `loopSheetName` does not exist in the target workbook. Perhaps someone has created a new sheet, or renamed an existing sheet in the source workbook.

---

You haven't asked about it, but you can improve the performance of your copy code as well, by reading the inputs as a multi-row range array, creating a row array to hold the results, and writing that once:

```
var sourceData = sourceSheet.getRange(6, 2, 5, 1).getValues(); // (6,2) through (10, 2)
var output = [];
// Transpose row array to column array (could use other functions, but this is easier to understand)
for(var i = 0; i < sourceData.length; ++i) { output.push(sourceData[i][0]); }
targetSheet.getRange(targetRow, 2, 1, output.length).setValues([output]); // i0 = 6 -> 6 - 4 = 2
```

Comment: That makes sense.  After looking into my code further, based on your observation, I realized that the issue was with my array.  Your info plus the tip from @tehhowch got me where I needed to go.

And thanks for the tip on the inner for-loop; I'll incorporate that as well, since this script could use some optimization.